# How to design a client server architecture for Swing clients and a database?

Tags: java, swing, architecture, client-server

I have written an application in java Swing that runs in 8 machines under a Local Area Network and accesses a mysql db. The program is running fine. But, now my client has decided to set up a new branch at a distant location which should be connected to the existing branch. How can I modify/extend my application to handle that situation.
client wants to use it in normal internet connection.any ideas will be great help.

Answer (score 5):

You should not connect directly from the Swing clients to the database. It's better if you implement a service to communicate with the database, and the Swing application communicate with the service.

The easiest thing may be to set up a web server, and communicate with JSON using an [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) in your Swing application. That is what I'm using.

In summary you need three parts:

- Swing client application, that has a built in HTTP Client. Communicates with a web server.
- A web server that responds to requests from client applications and is connected to the database via JDBC
- The database itself.

As Ajay suggests, the deployment will be easier if you use [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/).

Comment: thanks...alot....no worries if we don't know json ...just if we can upload sql file rather then sending json...everything willbe easy..thanks for the great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java Web Start. 
The client would download the jnlp file and open the GUI using that

Also have a clear separation between your view and model.
Your client will talk to a service which can give you the data from the DB.

Comment: thanks...alot....no worries if we don't know json ...just if we can upload sql file rather then sending json...everything willbe easy..thanks for the great idea.